# Launching Google Chrome from docky

Tags: google-chrome, docky

I have installed google-chrome-stable by using google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb on my ubuntu 14.04. I am able to start the browser by typing `google-chrome-stable` in my terminal. My issue is how do I launch chrome from docky.

I am able to add a link to chrome in my taskbar and when I click on this launcher icon another chrome-google-chrome icon gets added to the launcher as shown below :

[image: chrome starter]

and now I go to the docky, right click on the chrome icon and select 'Pin to dock'.
after this I close my browser. Now I try to relaunch the chrome by selecting the pinned google-chrome icon as shown below:

[image: chrome icon in docky]

but the chrome does not launch from here. I also tried dragging the 'Google Chrome' icon to docky but it doesnt get pinned to the dock.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, I get the same problem sometimes. What I did was locked the new one to docky and it stopped opening twice. The other suggestion is to remove all icons and kill all the chrome processes (do `pkill chrome`). Then open it from the dash, by searching and lock that ne in.

Comment: @Tim can you please explain what do you mean by lock the **new one**  to the docky.

Comment: So you click on the one already pinned, and another opens? Pin that to the dock.

Comment: @Tim I did exactly that, I already have one chrome icon which is locked to my launcher, ( which I am not able to add to the docky ) and when I click this in my launcher I chrome opens with a new icon, and this icon appears both in the launcher and the docky. Now when I right click on this new icon in the docky and select pin to dock, it is getting pinned. But next time when I try to launch it directly by clicking the chrome icon in docky, nothing happens !!! Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: @Tim That "other" suggestion you mentioned did the trick! Thanks! Those fuzzy icons were getting annoying.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 14.04? It looks like Mac.

Comment: @StarOS It is ubuntu, with Mac theme installed on it. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I have figured out the problem and here is what I did :

**Step 1 :** Uninstall Google Chrome

Type the following in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

**Step 2 :** Remove all chrome links

This was necessary because in my system, because Google Chrome icons were still present in spite of removing Chrome after Step 1.

```
sudo su
cd .local/share/applications
ls -l
```

I found that `google-chrome-stable.desktop` is still present here so I removed it by typing

```
rm -f -r google-chrome-stable.desktop
```

**Step 3 :** Reinstall Google Chrome

Download the latest `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` file (from [here](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb)),
and install it using Ubuntu Software Center.

**Step 4 :** Post Installation settings (Most Important)

Navigate to `/usr/share/applications` directory using GUI, then drag and drop the Google Chrome icon into the docky.

Thats it...
Now you can launch Google Chrome from docky with just a single icon.

Comment: Sometimes all you need is Step 4 only.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution without re-installing, because that did not work in my case:

1. Open `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` with sudo privileges in some editor.
2. Open Chromium or Chrome browser. It does not matter, if it shows in a different icon or not.
3. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   xprop | grep WM_CLASS
   ```
4. Your mouse pointer will change into a cross. With this cross click anywhere inside the Chrome/ium window. Something like this will show up in the terminal:

   ```
   WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Google-chrome-stable", "Google-chrome-stable"
   ```
5. In the editor, in which you opened the `*.desktop` file, write on the second line (after the `[Desktop Entry]`):

   ```
   StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable
   ```

   or `StartupWMClass=whatever-was-in-the-terminal-output` (in either of the quotes).
6. Save the file and the result should be seen immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The currently approved answer was solved only the pinning issue, but the ugly duplicated icon remained there.

1. Edit the desktop config file:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```
2. Insert the following code after the 3 group entries ([Desktop Entry], [NewWindow Shortcut Group], [NewIncognito Shortcut Group]):

   ```
   StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable
   ```
3. In case of Docky, stop Docky, remove the cache folder and restart Docky:

   ```
   ~/.cache/docky
   ```
4. If still have a problem look into the `~/.local/share/applications` folder and remove every `google-chrome-stable.desktop` files.

*Honestly this is a temporary solution, almost every Chrome update will reset the settings.*

I've found the solution on the following blog entry: [Fix double google chrome icon in docky and plank](http://kb.openstudioproject.com/content/fix-double-google-chrome-icon-docky-and-plank)